# (informal) Is the boundary of locally conformally flat Manifold also locally conformally flat

Tags: riemannian-geometry, conformal-geometry

Just a quick informal Question. I was wondering if the boundary of an LCF Manifold is also LCF ?
By definition a LCF manifold is one in which, for each point, there exists a neighborhood around that point that can be conformally transformed to a flat Euclidean space.
Since the boundary is a submanifold the answer to the above question should be, yes !
Do I have to be careful to which EUclidean Space i send the conformal transformation?
i.e should boundary points only be conformally mapped to an euclidean half space?
Thanks for clarification!

Comment: What is your definition of a conformally flat manifold with boundary? The definition that you wrote does not make sense in this setting.

Comment: I dont have a definition for a LCF Manifold with boundary. Can't find one in the literature thats why im asking. But the intuition says its just a Manifold with boundary in the normal sense and every neighbourhodd of a point interior or boundary can be conformally mapped to a flat space. Not sure why you saying it makes no sense since the definition just applies to points and neighbourhoods around them

Comment: "Conformally mapped to" does make sense,  unlike "transformed to." However, it has no implications as far as the boundary structure.